# Reading a frequency distribution from csv file into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file containing a frequency distribution, with data values(*xi*) and corresponding frequency(*fi*) of data value in two separate columns. I want to plot a histogram for the *xi*'s using the *fi* data.

I tried using the [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) function, which however, as I understood, assumed a set of discrete data points (unlike a frequency distribution) as the input.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Edit: This is a sample of how my data looks like 
[image]

Comment: Show a representative sample of your data and your expected output.

Comment: It sounds like what you have already is a histogram.  You have a count of each value `xi`.  Do you need to aggregate into wider binnings?

Comment: Yes, I already kind of have a histogrammed data set, just need to plot it